# Q promise chaining, error handler not called

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Consider this code

```
var tryWithoutReindexing = function(indexName, properties) {
        var settings = properties["settings"];
        var mappings = properties["mappings"];
        return elastic.closeIndex(indexName)
            .then(elastic.putSettings(indexName, settings))
            .then(elastic.putMapping(indexName, mappings))
            .then(elastic.openIndex(indexName));
};
```

And call:

```
tryWithoutReindexing(indexName, newProperties)
.then(function success(value){
         console.log('migration successful');
     }, function error(){
         console.log('migration unsuccessful');
     });
```

Method `elastic.putSettings` throws error, but for some reason, `console` logs `'migration is successful'`. I would expect error handler to be called.

If I change method to this:

```
var tryWithoutReindexing = function(indexName, properties) {
        var settings = properties["settings"];
        var mappings = properties["mappings"];
        return elastic.closeIndex(indexName)
            .then(elastic.putSettings(indexName, settings))
                .then(function success() {
                console.log('err');
            }, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(elastic.putMapping(indexName, mappings))
            .then(elastic.openIndex(indexName));
};
```

, and put breakpoint in line `console.log(error);`, the error handler is called, so it seems that putSettings method works correctly.

Does anyone can explain me why first example doesn't handle error raised in promise chain?

Comment: It doesn't seem that you're showing us your actual code. Your alternative version of the method has lines that assign `settings` and `mappings`, while your first version doesn't have this, but still uses those variables. Please pare your code down to something that actually produces the issue, but that you can copy here unmodified. We need to see actual code because the devil is in the details.

Comment: @JLRishe updated,  that  was the only difference, which I've omitted for brevity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `elastic.putSettings()` et al return a promise. You can't use a promise as an argument for `.then`; that method expects *function* arguments. In turn though, these functions can return a promise.

So, you need to wrap your promise-returning functions with an anonymous function, and use that function as the argument for the `.then`'s. Like so:

```
var tryWithoutReindexing = function(indexName, properties) {
  var settings = properties["settings"];
  var mappings = properties["mappings"];

  return elastic.closeIndex(indexName)
                .then(function() {
                  return elastic.putSettings(indexName, settings);
                })
                .then(function() {
                  return elastic.putMapping(indexName, mappings);
                })
                .then(function() {
                  return elastic.openIndex(indexName);
                });
};
```

Comment: ok, the answer is correct, but I need some clarification. elastic.putSettings(indexName, settings) is a function wrapper which returns promise: 
putSettings: function(indexName, settings){
        return client.indices.putSettings({
            index:indexName,
            body: settings
        });
    },

So why exactly this didn't work? This is a function argument, not a promise (I guess)

Comment: I understand I think. What I've done was calling function with arguments, which results in promise. Is there a way to pass function reference with arguments to bind? Fat arrows and function wrapper are options, but I'm looking for one liner for cleaner code

Comment: @Raston try this: `.then(elastic.putSettings.bind(elastic, indexName, settings))` (it does make the code more concise, but not necessarily cleaner IMO)